# Getting error file not found for ProcessCenter_CaseManagerConfig.properties while running BPMGenerateUpgradeSchemaScripts.bat command

Tags: installation, ibm-bpm

I am updating IBM BPM 8.6.0 to IBM Business Automation Workflow Version 18.0.0.2, after updating fix pack for IBAW when I am running below command I get an error.

```
BPMGenerateUpgradeSchemaScripts.bat -profileName Node1Profile  -de ProcessCenter
```

Below is the error which is coming on running above command.

Unable to find the response file

```
C:\IBM\BPM\v8.6\profiles\Node1Profile\config\cells\PCCell1\ProcessCenter_CaseManagerConfig.properties
Unable to find the file C:\IBM\BPM\v8.6\profiles\Node1Profile\config\cells\PCCell1\ProcessCenter_CaseManagerConfig.properties, please run the command 'BPMConfig -update -profile deployment_manager_profile -de deployment_environment_name -caseConfigure' to collect the configuration information for the content data sources, please read the knowledge center for details.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\IBM\BPM\v8.6\profiles\Node1Profile\config\cells\PCCell1\ProcessCenter_CaseManagerConfig.properties (The system cannot find the file specified.)
CWMCO6007E: The BPMGenerateUpgradeSchemaScripts command could not complete successfully. The following exception occurred :
Faild to initialize the CommonInfo. java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\IBM\BPM\v8.6\profiles\Node1Profile\config\cells\PCCell1\ProcessCenter_CaseManagerConfig.properties (The system cannot find the file specified.)
```

The file command asked to run first in the above error is on 11 point in the upgrade guide, can some one please suggest whats wrong with this?

Comment: Did you do what the line 2 in the error you pasted says?

Comment: First time I have done that but that upgrade also failed because of the sql files was not generated properly, So i rolled back and started again. And this error is coming my confusion here is that following IBM Upgrade doc, this command(BPMGenerateUpgradeSchemaScripts.bat) should be run first and BPMConfig -update command is on 11th point. So what is the right approach should i BPMConfig command on dmgr profile and than BPMGenerate?